# Did Jyn not believe that the Rebellion existed until now?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Captain Andor speaks to Jyn:

> Andor: We don't all have the luxury of deciding... when and where we
> want to care about something.
> **Suddenly the Rebellion is real for you**. Some of us live it. I've been in this fight since I was 6 years old.

Did Jyn didn't believe Rebellion exist till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly she knew about the Rebellion before - she had been part of Saw Gerrera's rebel group after escaping and hiding from Krennic as a young girl.

What Cassian means is that he believes Jyn has been ignoring the rebellion for the time since she left Gerrera's group, that she has simply been looking out for herself, and now she is being confronted with the reality of the rebellion again, while he has lived no other life since he was a child.

Comment: I think it's more that she has a **reason** to rebel, and that in the past she was merely involved in the rebellion because of her association with Saw.